# How to store python code in my database for a project running Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Basically, I want to store python modules with a few simple functions in my database. My project runs on Django. I came across [python_field](https://github.com/chrisspen/django-python-code-field), however, its buggy. I want to execute the code on the save method for the Model. What is the standard way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I think there's a larger question here.  _Why_ do you want to save code in a database?

Comment: I can't judge ... since they are people writing javascript on server side.

Answer (score 1):

I guess they are not a standard way to do it because it looks like an **antipattern**. Anyway, for academical purposes, you can try with:

```
from django.db import models
from python_field.fields import PythonCodeField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ....
    source = PythonCodeField(blank=True, null=True)

    ....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        codeObject = compile(self.source, '<string>', 'exec')
        exec( codeObject )  #executing before regular save
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        exec( codeObject )  #executing after regular save
```

Comment: OP already said python_field's buggy so any other alternative would be good rather than this one

Comment: @ArpitSolanki, just focused on question. I also included disclaimer. OP ask to execute it on save method, here it is ... with a big disclaimer. OP don't ask for alternative method. You agree?

Comment: I don't agree why he want to store the code in DB itself but answer is okay itself.

Comment: Nice! my answer is about how to do it, I do not judge whether that is good or bad. I disclaimed that for me looks like bad, but I don't know all the whole context :)